# Android/Java Development: How to change TextView text, using Java, to a predefined string in strings.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Ok, here is what I have:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    Spinner dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
    final String options[] = {"-Turf Diseases-", "Dollar Spot", "Red Thread"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options); 
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

    dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            newSelection(options[position]);                
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {} 
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void newSelection(String selection) {
    if(!selection.contains("-")) {
        title.setText(selection);
        selection=selection.replace(" ", "_");
        selection=selection.toUpperCase();
        description.setText("@string/DESC_"+selection);
    }
}
```

The string array of options[] holds titles of strains of lawn diseases (the purpose of the app).  It is in a spinner list in the main activity, and when a user clicks a title the action listener calls this last method, newSelection.  This method is supposed to format the title to: WORD_WORD.

I have the descriptions saved as predefined strings in strings.xml, all starting with DESC_WORD_WORD.  So by my logic, I could do this:    description.setText("@string/DESC_"+selection); and it would easily locate the corresponding description  in strings.xml.

This is, in fact, what has not ended up happening.  The text just changes to the "@string/DESC_WORD_WORD" instead of the  predefined string. I'm trying to think like an object-oriented programmer, but it isn't working out for me... I am fairly new to android, so go easy on me if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your resource by its string ID which is done thusly...

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static int getResourceId(String name,  Class resType){

        try {
            Class res = null;
            if(resType == R.drawable.class)
                res = R.drawable.class;
            if(resType == R.id.class)
                res = R.id.class;
            if(resType == R.string.class)
                res = R.string.class;
            Field field = res.getField(name);
            int retId = field.getInt(null);
            return retId;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           // Log.d(TAG, "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This is an example of a static method that will take a String that is your resource ID and the type of resource it is so you'd call it..

```
myText.setText( getResourceId("DESC_WORD_WORD", R.strings.class));
```

Comment: Understood, removing my answer as it won't help the OP.

Comment: Dude,  I couldn't have asked for a better answer.  I basically copied what you had there and made the required alterations - worked like a charm.  Thank you very much for  the quick response, too!  I just wish I understood exactly what is going on there... Why the Field, and not the int?  Why is the argument for field.getInt null?  For that matter... what is a field? lol

Comment: I just broke it up to make it clearer (perhaps it only made it more obtuse).  The bottom line is that R has a bunch of items that map to the generated numeric ideas.  Field allows you to get back to that number from the String. Passing 0 as an id to setText() will simply do nothing, so it's safe to return 0 in the event that it fails to locate the id in R represented by your input String. Hopefully that makes sense. (and you're welcome! :) )